# What's wrong with my PATH setup? Error: ".. is not recognized as an internal or external command.."

Tags: python, command-line, environment-variables, command-prompt

I've written a basic script, but whenever I try to run it in the terminal, I get this error :

> .. is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

I believe I've downloaded and installed everything (python, pip, visual studio) correctly. I've set up my environment variables according to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=50&v=Y2q_b4ugPWk) and according to the test he performs at the end, my path is set up correctly. I've tried restarting my computer, etc.

I've scoured forums and watched youtube tutorials, and nothing seems to hit exactly on my problem. I don't think my code is faulty, but I can include some pictures of the error messages as well as some other info that may or may not be helpful. Here is the error message: [image: error]

It seems like my `Path` goes to my Python Projects folder when I go to Systems Variables: [image: System Variable PATH]

BUT when I I don't see "Python Projects".
[image: Echo Path]

Here is the script:

```
import math
a = float(input("What is the a value? "))
b = float(input("What is the b value? "))
c = float(input("What is the c value? "))
result = (-1 * b + math.sqrt(math.pow(b, 2) -(4*a*c))) / 2*a
result2 = (-1 * b - math.sqrt(math.pow(b, 2) -(4*a*c))) / 2*a
print(result)
print(result2)
```

Comment: it'd be nice if we could see your script and not the video

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: In fact you don't need to install python on your computer, just experiment in any online IDE such as https://ideone.com/

Comment: ...or replace `quadratic` by `python`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python; you simply need to learn how to use the Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

`python` is the command to run a python script.

So, you need to do `python scriptname.py`.  Also, you should try to not have spaces in your file names - it makes it harder.  So if you rename your file as `quadraticformula.py`, you should be able to run it as `python quadraticformula.py`.